# Where can I download old iOS versions from Apple?

Tags: ios, upgrade, developer-program

I need to test my app with older version of iOS and can't find exactly where to download them from Apple.

Anybody know the adress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Apple doesn't offer the links directly, but [iClarified has a complete list of iOS downloads for all models of iPhone available here](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750). It came in handy when I downgraded my old 3G back down to 3.1.3

Comment: It's also worth noting that you may not be able to downgrade the OS on your device as the baseband may no longer be compatible. This is more of an issue on iPhones than iPod Touches though.

Comment: That iClarified site does not have iPod Touch downloads. Is there a site with the old versions of iPod Touch software?

Comment: @Greg: They also have a list of iPod Touch downloads: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=757

Comment: This site has more links and directly from apple.com: http://leimobile.com/firmware-downloads/

Comment: Check [IPSW](https://ipsw.me). They have downloads available for all the older iOS releases for all the devices. Do note that not all the older os images are signed by Apple and hence you may not be actually install an image that you obtain.

Comment: Here's another option for a site with links for IPSW downloads directly from Apple: http://osxdaily.com/tag/ipsw/

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://ipsw.me Here you can download so many .ipsw